# Xpath - how to get parent based on its child's attribute

Tags: xpath

I have XML like below

```
<root>
<Success />
<Warnings>
</Warnings>
<Results>
    <Result SequenceNumber="1"> 
        <ResultchildOne>
            <ResultChildOTwo>
                <ElementA>
                    <ElementB ImportantAttribute="xxx" >
                    </ElementB>
                </ElementA>
                <ElementA>
                    <ElementB ImportantAttribute="yyy">
                    </ElementB>
                </ElementA>
            </ResultChildOTwo>
        </ResultchildOne>      
    </Result>
    <Result SequenceNumber="1">
        <ResultchildOne>
            <ResultChildOTwo>
                <ElementA>
                    <ElementB ImportantAttribute="another value">
                    </ElementB>
                </ElementA>
                <ElementA>
                    <ElementB ImportantAttribute="xxx" >
                    </ElementB>
                </ElementA>
            </ResultChildOTwo>
        </ResultchildOne>
    </Result>
</Results>
```

I try to write xPath to select all Result elements which first child node ElementB has attribute ImportantAttribute="xxx" and its second child node ElementB has attribute ImportantAttribute="yyy". Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

This works for the sample document:

```
//Result[ResultchildOne/ResultChildOTwo[ElementA[1]/ElementB[@ImportantAttribute='xxx']]
                                       [ElementA[2]/ElementB[@ImportantAttribute='yyy']]]
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried to do it in more compliated way (with axes), but you did it in much more simple way.